# Cannot connect Prometheus to Kafka broker (Get "http://host:port/metrics" : EOF) using docker compose

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, jmx

My setup is a docker container of **confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2** image with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    container_name: broker-1
    user: root
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=10.200.125.24:2181,10.200.125.11:2181,10.200.115.66:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT  
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://10.200.125.24:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker-1:29092
      - KAFKA_JMX_PORT=9101
      - KAFKA_JMX_REMOTE_HOSTNAME=10.200.125.24
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
volumes:
  kafka_data:
```

and a docker container of prom/prometheus image with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

and the following config file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kafka'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['10.200.125.24:9101']
```

My cluster consists of 3 broker nodes and 3 zookeeper nodes and seem to be working properly.
I verified that jmxremote must be working properly on 10.200.125.24:9101 by running the following jmxterm commands in the host machine:
[jmxterm results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iQxh.png)

I also verified that from within the prometheus container I can succssfully telnet on 10.200.125.24:9101

However, the problem is that Prometheus cannot connect to kafka metrics url (http://10.200.125.24:9101/metrics) and all I get is the following error:

```
Get "http://10.200.125.24:9101/metrics": EOF
```

[prometheus screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhB8G.png)

I tried to curl (http://10.200.125.24:9101/metrics) from the host machine but all i get is this:

```
curl --noproxy '*' http://10.200.125.24:9101/metrics
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

I tried to connect prometheus to kafka broker and I expected to read metrics in prometheus. Prometheus cannot connect to the kafka broker.

Comment: The Kafka container doesn't run any http metrics endpoint on its own. JMX remote settings have nothing to do with Promethus JMX exporter, which must be setup separately. You could instead try Strimzi in Kubernetes instead of Docker Compose, which does offer the JMX exporter setup, then also use Prometheus Operator to scrape it